# vim returns 1 on exit

Tags: vim, mercurial

I use vim as an editor for hg. So every time I want to check something in, hg fires up vim to enter the check in message. When finished, I close vim with :wq and hg takes the file and extracts the check in message from it. This works fine on our working group server. But on my local Mac (OS X 10.10) vim returns `1`, which makes hg think that there went something wrong when entering the check in message and prevents me from checking in.

So the question is: How to find out why vim returns 1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you use 'vi' as symlink to vim? That can apparently cause [issues](https://github.com/Shougo/neobundle.vim/issues/192).

Try adding the following (or use a more recent vim) and see if this fixes it:

```
[ui]
editor = vim
```

Comment: Perfect. I was sure that I added this into my hgrc, but apparently this was also on our remote server. Adding it locally fixed the problem. Thanks.